ECSAllAtOnce does not respect health checks
I have an ECS Service with FARGATE launch type. I also use CodeDeploy to do deployments.
My problem is that when I use CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce the health status of the new target is not respected. Even if it is not healthy the deployment continues and traffic gets rerouted to a non-responsive instance.
If I use, say CodeDeployDefault.ECSLinear10PercentEvery1Minutes then the health status is taken into account and the deployment doesn’t go to the next step which is good.
I want the deployment to switch all instances at the same time and I also want to make sure it only happens if the new targets are healthy.
How can I achieve this?
These are the relevant snippets from the CloudFormation template:
  EcsService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn:
      - TargetGroup1
      - TargetGroup2
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref EnvironmentName
      DeploymentController: 
        Type: CODE_DEPLOY
      DesiredCount: 1
      HealthCheckGracePeriodSeconds: !Ref HealthCheckGracePeriod
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      LoadBalancers: 
        - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup1
          ContainerName: !Ref EnvironmentName
          ContainerPort: 8080
      NetworkConfiguration: 
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
            Subnets: [ !Ref PrivateSubnet1, !Ref PrivateSubnet2 ]
            SecurityGroups: [ !Ref ECSHostSecurityGroup ]
            AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
      PlatformVersion: LATEST
      SchedulingStrategy: REPLICA
      ServiceName: !Ref EnvironmentName
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition

  CodeDeployDeploymentGroup:
    Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup
    DependsOn: EcsService
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref EnvironmentName
      DeploymentGroupName: !Ref EnvironmentName
      DeploymentConfigName: CodeDeployDefault.ECSLinear10PercentEvery1Minutes. # Want ECSAllAtOnce though!
      ServiceRoleArn: !GetAtt EcsRoleForCodeDeploy.Arn
      DeploymentStyle:
        DeploymentType: BLUE_GREEN
        DeploymentOption: WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL
      BlueGreenDeploymentConfiguration:
        TerminateBlueInstancesOnDeploymentSuccess:
          Action: TERMINATE
          TerminationWaitTimeInMinutes: 0
        DeploymentReadyOption: 
          ActionOnTimeout: STOP_DEPLOYMENT
          WaitTimeInMinutes: 9
      LoadBalancerInfo:
          TargetGroupPairInfoList:
            - TargetGroups:
              - Name: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-1
              - Name: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-2
              ProdTrafficRoute:
                ListenerArns: [ !Ref ALBListenerHTTPS ]
      ECSServices:
        - ServiceName: !Ref EnvironmentName
          ClusterName: !Ref EnvironmentName


Found a solution to the problem. Added an extra health check in the TaskDefinition (rather ContainerDefinition) for the ECS Service.
Previously I had the health check only at TargetGroup level. Now I have the same health check in the container definition as well. This stops the deployment at the first/provisioning step when using "ECSAllAtOnce".
Personally, I find it illogical that ECSLinear10PercentEvery1Minutes triggers the health check at TargetGroup level but ECSAllAtOnce does not. Maybe my limited DevOps knowledge plays tricks on me.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
